# How to configure the nvcc compiler for using Eigen library?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cuda, eigen, nvcc

I had an absolutely working project containing the Eigen 3.4.0. After installing Сuda 12.0, Visual Studio began to issue an error at the compilation stage on the script in the Eigen library itself in the project. This is happening in the file NumTraits.h in the part:

```
struct default_digits10_impl<T,false,false> // Floating point
{
  EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC EIGEN_CONSTEXPR
  static int run() {
    using std::log10;
    using std::ceil;
    typedef typename NumTraits<T>::Real Real;
    return int(ceil(-log10(NumTraits<Real>::epsilon())));
  }
```

C2665   "log10": no overloaded function can convert all types of arguments - this is error.

The library is external, I don't want to make changes in this code, I want to understand how to avoid this error.

I tried to paste

```
#if (defined __GNUC__) && (__GNUC__>4 || __GNUC_MINOR__>=7)
  #undef _GLIBCXX_ATOMIC_BUILTINS
  #undef _GLIBCXX_USE_INT128
#endif
```

in main  file and define EIGEN_DEFAULT_DENSE_INDEX_TYPE, as it write in the description of Cuda and Eigen compatibility. But it didn't help.

Here is an addition to the question:
the error occurs when initializing a variable with the type:

`using CubeXX3d = Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::Vector3d, -1, -1>;`

Comment: The Eigen documentation suggests that Eigen CUDA integration doesn't work with Visual Studio https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCUDA.html, it is gcc/linux only

Answer (score 1):

This error occurred only because I submitted an instance of the CubeXX3d class for output:

```
std::cout<<instance;
```

(the CubeXX3d class definition is described above).
After I deleted this line, there was no error.